# Azure search is returning Invalid Expression with Date Filter

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am running into an issue with Azure search which was working before but now 
receiving Invalid Expression. Am I missing something.
Date Type of the filter filed-

{  "name": "ModifiedDateTime",
  "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset",
  "searchable": false,
  "filterable": true,
  "facetable": true,
  "sortable": true }

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rovb.png)

Api-version=2016-09-01-Preview

Request-

{"queryType":"full","searchMode":"all","filter":"ModifiedDateTime ge 2018-12-12","search":null,"searchFields":null,"count":true}

Error -

{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "Invalid expression: Literal '2018-12-12' of unsupported data type 'Date' was found. Please use a literal that matches the type of the field in the expression.\r\nParameter name: $filter"
    }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error was caused by a regression that has since been fixed. Only Search services in West Central US were affected.

We had missing test coverage for this case, which we actually never intended to support. Although we have fixed this to avoid breaking backward compatibility, we may remove the ability to use `Edm.Date` literals in filters in a future API version.

You should always include the time and offset portions as well when comparing with dates. Otherwise, how do you decide when one day starts and the next begins? We assume midnight UTC for plain dates, but this assumption may not be valid for your users.

We recommend writing filters on `Edm.DateTimeOffset` fields like this instead:

```
ModifiedDateTime ge 2018-12-12T00:00:00Z
```

The Z is for UTC, to which Azure Search normalizes all DateTimeOffset values.

Comment: Thanks for the response Bruce. but I wonder is this due to some recent update on Azure search.. Just few days back this query was returning matched response.

Comment: You're right, this was due to a recent change and it shouldn't have happened. I've updated my answer to reflect this. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @BruceJohnston I'm facing a similar issue with .NET SDK for Azure Search, Filter = "Date ge 2017-04-14T06:35:05Z" this my query. It works fine in Azure Search Explorer in the Azure Portal. But when I use the SDK's SearchClient.Search method I'm getting results as null. In the Azure portal this same query is giving some documents as result, Any Idea what went wrong here ?  Note: This issue is only for Edm.DateTimeOffset fields, filters on other working fine.

Comment: @Hari That's a different issue than the one described by the original question. Please create a new question for this, tag it with azure-cognitive-search, and include as many details as possible.